# ¿C'omo seleccionar registros que cumplan valores diferentes de un mismo campo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 create table test(
 nombre varchar2(20),
 posicion varchar2(20));

 insert into test values ('juan', 'defensa');
 insert into test values ('juan', 'medio');
 insert into test values ('jaime', 'defensa');
 insert into test values ('alberto', 'medio');

 --select nombre from test where posicion ='defensa' or posicion='medio';
```

> Cita en bloque

-->esto me devuelve si tienen una u otra posición pero deseo saber que registro cumple con ambos valores, 'defensa' y ',medio'. Gracias

Comment: Mil gracias por la premura, la respuesta y la sencillez de la misma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agrupar los resultados por nombre y quedarte solo con aquellos que tengan dos posiciones dentro de las seleccionadas:

```
select nombre 
       from test 
       where posicion ='defensa' 
             or posicion='medio'
       group by nombre
       having count(1) =  2;
```

Comment: Mil gracias por la premura, la respuesta y la sencillez de la misma –